# save a username to registry each time

Tags: c#, registry

I want to be able to save the email and password of the user everytime an email is added. I want to use the Windows Registry for this so that everytime the user opens the window, he finds the list of accounts still saved. However, I don't know how I can save them in a way t retrieve them.

string test = RegistryHelper.getSetting("user", "username", null)

this will retrieve the value for the key 'username' but not all the users.

is there a way I can append to a registry value for a certain key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel. Use C# settings to store values runtime:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

And use a `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` to store the usernames